# How to determine user reached the top of a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

So what I'm trying to do is, whenever the user scrolls down in the recyclerview, the top part should be resized to a height of 0 and whenever the user scrolls to the very top of the recyclerview it should be resized back to normal size.

This is the UI

[image]

This is how I handle it, but it's not working properly.

```
//sellerItems = the recyclerview
        sellerItems.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                val manager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
                if (recyclerView.scrollState == 2 && dy < 0) {
                    val pram = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    )
                    userStuff.layoutParams = pram
                }else if (dy > 0) {
                    val pram = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            0
                    )
                    userStuff.layoutParams = pram
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: You can use `collapsing toolbar layout` for this purpose.

Comment: `Collapsing Toolbar` is the best way to implement [Referance Link](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)